# Test password protected page django

Tags: django, django-testing, django-tests

I want to write test cases about password-protected pages.
I have **/management/edit** page. it is loginrequired page. My test case currently likes below, but it is failed. I am expecting to get 200 but instead of I got redirection(302)
**Tests.py**
from django.test import TestCase, Client

```
# Admin panel Test cases


class PageTest(TestCase):

    # it will redirect user to loginpage
    def test_admin_page(self):
        response = self.client.get("/management/")
        self.assertEquals(response.status_code, 302)

    def test_edit(self):
        c = Client()
        c.login(username='admin', password='admin')
        response = c.get("/management/edit/")
        self.assertEquals(response.status_code,200)
```

Answer (score 0):

I replaced **login** with **force_login**

```
   c = self.client
    testuser = User.objects.create_user(username='useresu', password='666pass')
    c.force_login(testuser)
```